# AWS ECS: which networking mode for best performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, amazon-ecs

I am evaluating which [networking mode to use on AWS ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode.html) for the best performance. I am not sure between `host` and `awspcs`. With `host` basically the container is attached directly to the network interface of the underlying EC2 bypassing Docker networking entirely while with `awsvpc` a new network interface is created for the container (in this case you can use port mapping and have different containers running on the same port, this is not possible with `host` mode).
Is there any performance difference between the two modes?

Comment: does the below answer help you? kindly post an update

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood reading the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode.html) (and some of the information below is what you've already figured out/mentioned) when using the `host` network mode the networking of the container is tied directly to the underlying host that's running the container bypassing Docker networking entirely. Now this should mean there is a higher network performance as there is no additional overhead of more than one network interface, routing via NAT, port mapping etc.

With `awsvpc` network mode Amazon ECS creates and manages an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) (separate from the underlying hosts ENI) for each task and each task receives its own private IP address within the VPC (pretty much what you've figured out already). But with that greater flexibility to control communications between tasks and services at a more granular level there has to be an additional overhead of routing traffic through an additional ENI and NAT.

There are some drawbacks associated with both, but going by the docs, more significant ones, including security implications, lie at the door of the `host` network mode.

Hope it helps you make a decision.

Comment: Yes, there coul be an overhead in latency between awsvpc and host although it is not clear how much it could be. I couldn't find any documentation about it. I guess the only way is to perform some real tests for comparison.